# VS Code pytest can't find any tests in workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I am trying to migrate my python project from pycharm to vs code. I have PyTest setup in vs-code but none of the tests are being found even though running pytest from the command line works fine. On the left side in the "Testing" section where should be project tests I am getting the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'YADAYADA'", maybe somebody knows how to fix this?

I have tried to add **init**.py file to every folder and subfolder

Comment: If it is an issue with imports, try running it like this:
`python -m pytest tests_folder/`

Comment: With this line tests are running, but I want to see all tests in testing tab

Answer (score -1):

Vscode uses the currently open folder as the workspace. You need to open your project folder with vscode. In addition, you also need to install necessary extensions for it, such as [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).

Tests can be configured in the test panel on the left. You can also use `Python: Configure Tests` from the command palette at any time.

[image]

Read the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_configure-tests) for details.

Comment: everything what is mentioned in documentation I have tried, I have python and also I have configured  python tests with pytest

Comment: Can you provide details and reproducible steps. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)